# Trying to calcula execution time in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

If I do a code like this:

```
foreachRDD{ rdd => 
  //operation1
  val before = time.now()
  val result = rdd.map(r=> //some operation)
  val finalTime = time.now() - before

  //operation1
  val before2 = time.now()
  val result2 = result.map(r=> //some operation)
  val finalTime2 = time.now() - before2

  ....   
  //Some action
}
```

I think that finalTime and finalTime2 are executed in the driver and they give me the real time to execute each of these operations, am I right? or these operations where are really executed?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `time` function, but only available only after `2.1.0` (You can add manually for the lower versions.)

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark test")
  .master("local[*]")
  .getOrCreate()

val df = ???
spark.time(df.show()) //some block of operation here
```

You can see here

> /**
>          * Executes some code block and prints to stdout the time taken to execute the block. This is
>          * available in Scala only and is used primarily for interactive testing and debugging.
>          *
>          * @since 2.1.0
>          */
>
> ```
> def time[T](f: => T): T = {
>     val start = System.nanoTime()
>     val ret = f
>     val end = System.nanoTime()
>     // scalastyle:off println
>     println(s"Time taken: ${(end - start) / 1000 / 1000} ms")
>     // scalastyle:on println
>     ret
>   }
> ```

Comment: It seems same I said. Unfortunately, I use Spark 2.0.2

Comment: You can manually add the function on your code and cal; simply as `time(query)`

Comment: Then, this code is executed in the driver before and after the execution? (I mean,  when it get the measures of system time).